# Naturality of the transfer in group cohomology

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, at.algebraic-topology, reference-request

Let $G$ be a (discrete) group and $H\le G$ a subgroup of finite index. Then there is a transfer map 
$$tr\colon\thinspace H^\ast(H;M)\to H^\ast(G;M)
$$
in group cohomology, where $M$ is any $G$-module (see Brown's "Cohomology of groups", Chapter III).

I think this construction should be natural, in the following sense. Let $f\colon\thinspace G'\to G$ be a homomorphism such that $H':=f^{-1}(H)$ is of finite index in $G'$, and let $M$ be a $G$-module. Then the following diagram commutes, where the horizontal maps are transfers:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
H^\ast(H;M) & \to & H^\ast(G;M) \newline
\downarrow f^\ast &  & \downarrow f^\ast \newline
H^\ast(H';f^\ast M) & \to & H^\ast(G';f^\ast M)
\end{array}
$$
Note that I do not want to assume that $(G':H')=(G:H)$ (however, I am willing to assume that $H\le G$ and $H'\le G'$ are normal, if necessary).

> Does anyone know of a reference for this naturality?

Comment: Thinking in terms of covering spaces, I would guess that what you need to assume is that the map of sets $G'/H'\to G/H$ is a bijection. If $H$ is normal then you have the injectivity, but you do need the surjectivity, too. Think of the case when $f$ is the inclusion $H\to G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe this is true. Let $(G, H) = (\Sigma_3, C_3)$ and $f : C_3 \to \Sigma_3$. Then your square says that
$$H^1(C_3;\mathbb{Z}/3) = \mathbb{Z}/3 \longrightarrow H^1(\Sigma_3;\mathbb{Z}/3) = 0\longrightarrow H^1(C_3;\mathbb{Z}/3) = \mathbb{Z}/3$$
is the identity, which is false.

Comment: The problem is that the pullback of $EG'\to BG'$ via $Bf$ is only connected if $f$ is surjective. If $f$ is surjective, the naturality holds.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I came close to writing "or counter-example" in the question (honest)! I'll try to think more about what *is* true, and may post here when I figure it out.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems the best one can hope for is the double coset formula (Proposition III.9.5(iii) in Brown) which applies when $f\colon G'\to G$ is a monomorphism.